# Database / Schema structure to build a Wall system

Tags: php, database-design, social-networking

I've been doing some researches about how to build a wall system similar to FB in PHP.

We planned to use an **ODM** ([Mandango](http://mandango.org), MongoDB) instead of a regular ORM (MySQL) to achieve this. Some friend told me about *inbox/outboxes* system.

- **Inbox** are all the messages that friends posts to your wall
- **Outbox** are all the message you post

Why that ? Because it'll be simplier if you follow an user, you'll follow only his "*outbox*"

Each time i'll post something to my wall, this message will be duplicated to each of my followers (which will generate a lot of data).
But what about when a friend comments my post. On which entity is he going to comment my post ? Mine or his (because the content is duplicated) ?

What do you think ?
Have you already thought of this kind of question ? Have you any answers ? 
Thanks

Comment: There are [a few potential dups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-design+social-networking) of this scattered on SO (also check database+social-networking). Look for questions related to activity stream, activity feed, and possibly audit logging.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about how you set up your database. I only have limited experience with MySql, so my answer relates to that. In this situation I would have at least these three tables:

-Users (with a unique id associated with each one)

-Messages: this includes both "inbox" and "outbox" messages. The reason you can put them all in one table is because if you're following someone, it will only pull those messages that have the (this is once column) "originating user id" and (this could be another column) "receiving user id" or some such thing. How you handle the data would all be done with php or asp or what have you.

-Comments: this holds all comments for all posts, and includes a column for the unique id of the message it relates to.

One thing to keep in mind when developing your system is that you never want to duplicate data. So, when you post to your wall, you don't want to actually create duplicate messages in your database for all the people who are following you, you want php to handle disseminating that information for you.

Comment: I guess it's more complicate than just "never duplicate data". Think of when the friend delete another friends status. With duplicate data, you just simply remove the raw without affecting others view's. Both approaches has advantages / cons